# PXSelector allowEdit

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

How do you make the allowEdit choice on selector fields on the grid available in the layout editor?

It seems that allowEdit choice on selector fields only works on forms but not on grids.

Answer (score 0):

AllowEdit can be used in a grid under the RowTemplate of the grid. Example below shows a grid with an OrderNbr field (sample from Sales Order Page SO301000):

```
<px:PXGridLevel DataMember="posupply">
    <Columns>
        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="OrderNbr" Width="80px" />
    </Columns>
    <RowTemplate>
        <px:PXSelector ID="edOrderNbr" runat="server" DataField="OrderNbr" AllowEdit="True" />
    </RowTemplate>
</px:PXGridLevel>
```

Comment: Isn't the RowTemplate a form layout not a grid layout? I'm interested in the grid itself.

Comment: When inside a grid component like `px:PXGridLevel` the `RowTemplate` sets the properties for the controls that are shown when editing a cell.

Comment: Does it affect the grid columns as well since RowTemplate only applies to controls on formEdit of a grid not on the columns itself? From what I understand, there is a difference between columns and controls. Controls are on the forms (including formEdit of a grid) while columns are on the grids.

Comment: No you define allowedit, is a selector, etc. using RowTemplate for a grid column. It would also be used in the grid form view if using that too. The above example is from a standard Acumatica screen. RowTemplate entries are not necessary for a field unless you need to define a specific control or property beyond the default the page uses. So not all fields need to be listed in RowTemplate for a grid that are listed under Columns. But for AllowEdit you will need to add your entry under RowTemplate to get it to work